# D3 skipping first two features in a TopoJson

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topojson

I am creating an interactive visualization tool with D3. I just got my map working today and I noticed that the first two features from the topojson are not loading in.

The first two entries of the topojson look like this and geojson.io reads these countries in fine. (They appear on the map)

```
 "objects":{"ne_10m_admin_0_countries":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"arcs":[[[0,1]],[[2,3,4,5]],[[6,7]],[[8,9]],[[10]],[[11]],[[12]],[[13]],[[14]],[[15]],[[16]],[[17]],[[18]],[[19]],[[20]],[[21]],[[22]],[[23]],[[24]],[[25]],[[26]],[[27]],[[28]],[[29]],[[30]],[[31]],[[32]],[[33]],[[34]],[[35]],[[36]],[[37]],[[38]],[[39]],[[40]],[[41]],[[42]],[[43]],[[44]],[[45]],[[46]],[[47]],[[48]],[[49]],[[50]],[[51]],[[52]],[[53]],[[54]],[[55]],[[56]],[[57]],[[58]],[[59]],[[60]],[[61]],[[62]],[[63]],[[64]],[[65]],[[66]],[[67]],[[68]],[[69]],[[70]],[[71]],[[72]],[[73]],[[74]],[[75]],[[76]],[[77]],[[78]],[[79]],[[80]],[[81]],[[82]],[[83]],[[84]],[[85]],[[86]],[[87]],[[88]],[[89]],[[90]],[[91]],[[92]],[[93]],[[94]],[[95]],[[96]],[[97]],[[98]],[[99]],[[100]],[[101]],[[102]],[[103]],[[104]],[[105]],[[106]],[[107]],[[108]],[[109]],[[110]],[[111]],[[112]],[[113]],[[114]],[[115]],[[116]],[[117]],[[118]],[[119]],[[120]],[[121]],[[122]],[[123]],[[124]],[[125]],[[126]],[[127]],[[128]],[[129]],[[130]],[[131]]],"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"featurecla":"Admin-0 country","scalerank":5,"LABELRANK":2,"SOVEREIGNT":"Indonesia","SOV_A3":"IDN","ADM0_DIF":0,"LEVEL":2,"TYPE":"Sovereign country","ADMIN":"Indonesia","ADM0_A3":"IDN","GEOU_DIF":0,"GEOUNIT":"Indonesia","GU_A3":"IDN","SU_DIF":0,"SUBUNIT":"Indonesia","SU_A3":"IDN","BRK_DIFF":0,"NAME":"Indonesia","NAME_LONG":"Indonesia","BRK_A3":"IDN","BRK_NAME":"Indonesia","BRK_GROUP":"","ABBREV":"Indo.","POSTAL":"INDO","FORMAL_EN":"Republic of Indonesia","FORMAL_FR":"","NAME_CIAWF":"Indonesia","NOTE_ADM0":"","NOTE_BRK":"","NAME_SORT":"Indonesia","NAME_ALT":"","MAPCOLOR7":6,"MAPCOLOR8":6,"MAPCOLOR9":6,"MAPCOLOR13":11,"POP_EST":260580739,"POP_RANK":17,"GDP_MD_EST":3028000,"POP_YEAR":2017,"LASTCENSUS":2010,"GDP_YEAR":2016,"ECONOMY":"4. Emerging region: MIKT","INCOME_GRP":"4. Lower middle income","WIKIPEDIA":-99,"FIPS_10_":"ID","ISO_A2":"ID","ISO_A3":"IDN","ISO_A3_EH":"IDN","ISO_N3":"360","UN_A3":"360","WB_A2":"ID","WB_A3":"IDN","WOE_ID":23424846,"WOE_ID_EH":23424846,"WOE_NOTE":"Exact WOE match as country","ADM0_A3_IS":"IDN","ADM0_A3_US":"IDN","ADM0_A3_UN":-99,"ADM0_A3_WB":-99,"CONTINENT":"Asia","REGION_UN":"Asia","SUBREGION":"South-Eastern Asia","REGION_WB":"East Asia & Pacific","NAME_LEN":9,"LONG_LEN":9,"ABBREV_LEN":5,"TINY":-99,"HOMEPART":1,"MIN_ZOOM":0,"MIN_LABEL":1.7,"MAX_LABEL":6.7,"NE_ID":1159320845,"WIKIDATAID":"Q252","NAME_AR":"إندونيسيا","NAME_BN":"ইন্দোনেশিয়া","NAME_DE":"Indonesien","NAME_EN":"Indonesia","NAME_ES":"Indonesia","NAME_FR":"Indonésie","NAME_EL":"Ινδονησία","NAME_HI":"इंडोनेशिया","NAME_HU":"Indonézia","NAME_ID":"Indonesia","NAME_IT":"Indonesia","NAME_JA":"インドネシア","NAME_KO":"인도네시아","NAME_NL":"Indonesië","NAME_PL":"Indonezja","NAME_PT":"Indonésia","NAME_RU":"Индонезия","NAME_SV":"Indonesien","NAME_TR":"Endonezya","NAME_VI":"Indonesia","NAME_ZH":"印度尼西亚"}},{"arcs":[[[132,-1]],[[133,134]],[[135,-8,136,137,138,139]],[[140]],[[141]],[[142]],[[143]],[[144]],[[145]]],"type":"MultiPolygon","properties":{"featurecla":"Admin-0 country","scalerank":5,"LABELRANK":3,"SOVEREIGNT":"Malaysia","SOV_A3":"MYS","ADM0_DIF":0,"LEVEL":2,"TYPE":"Sovereign country","ADMIN":"Malaysia","ADM0_A3":"MYS","GEOU_DIF":0,"GEOUNIT":"Malaysia","GU_A3":"MYS","SU_DIF":0,"SUBUNIT":"Malaysia","SU_A3":"MYS","BRK_DIFF":0,"NAME":"Malaysia","NAME_LONG":"Malaysia","BRK_A3":"MYS","BRK_NAME":"Malaysia","BRK_GROUP":"","ABBREV":"Malay.","POSTAL":"MY","FORMAL_EN":"Malaysia","FORMAL_FR":"","NAME_CIAWF":"Malaysia","NOTE_ADM0":"","NOTE_BRK":"","NAME_SORT":"Malaysia","NAME_ALT":"","MAPCOLOR7":2,"MAPCOLOR8":4,"MAPCOLOR9":3,"MAPCOLOR13":6,"POP_EST":31381992,"POP_RANK":15,"GDP_MD_EST":863000,"POP_YEAR":2017,"LASTCENSUS":2010,"GDP_YEAR":2016,"ECONOMY":"6. Developing region","INCOME_GRP":"3. Upper middle income","WIKIPEDIA":-99,"FIPS_10_":"MY","ISO_A2":"MY","ISO_A3":"MYS","ISO_A3_EH":"MYS","ISO_N3":"458","UN_A3":"458","WB_A2":"MY","WB_A3":"MYS","WOE_ID":23424901,"WOE_ID_EH":23424901,"WOE_NOTE":"Exact WOE match as country","ADM0_A3_IS":"MYS","ADM0_A3_US":"MYS","ADM0_A3_UN":-99,"ADM0_A3_WB":-99,"CONTINENT":"Asia","REGION_UN":"Asia","SUBREGION":"South-Eastern Asia","REGION_WB":"East Asia & Pacific","NAME_LEN":8,"LONG_LEN":8,"ABBREV_LEN":6,"TINY":-99,"HOMEPART":1,"MIN_ZOOM":0,"MIN_LABEL":3,"MAX_LABEL":8,"NE_ID":1159321083,"WIKIDATAID":"Q833","NAME_AR":"ماليزيا","NAME_BN":"মালয়েশিয়া","NAME_DE":"Malaysia","NAME_EN":"Malaysia","NAME_ES":"Malasia","NAME_FR":"Malaisie","NAME_EL":"Μαλαισία","NAME_HI":"मलेशिया","NAME_HU":"Malajzia","NAME_ID":"Malaysia","NAME_IT":"Malesia","NAME_JA":"マレーシア","NAME_KO":"말레이시아","NAME_NL":"Maleisië","NAME_PL":"Malezja","NAME_PT":"Malásia","NAME_RU":"Малайзия","NAME_SV":"Malaysia","NAME_TR":"Malezya","NAME_VI":"Malaysia","NAME_ZH":"马来西亚"}},{"arcs":[[[146,147,148,149]],[[150,151,152,153]],[[154]],[[155]],[[156]],[[157]],[[158]],[[159]],[[160]],[[161]],[[162]],[[163]],[[164]],[[165]],[[166]],[[167]],[[168]],[[169]],[[170]],[[171]],[[172]],[[173]],[[174]],[[175]],[[176]],[[177]],[[178]],[[179]],[[180]],[[181]],[[182]],[[183]],[[184]],[[185]],[[186]],[[187]],[[188]],[[189]],[[190]],[[191]],[[192]],[[193]],[[194]],[[195]],[[196]],[[197]],[[198]],[[199]],[[200]],[[201]],[[202]],[[203]],[[204]],[[205]],[[206]],[[207]],[[208]],[[209]],[[210]],[[211]],[[212]],[[213]],[[214]],[[215]],[[216]],[[217]],[[218]],[[219]],[[220]],[[221]],[[222]],[[223]],[[224]],[[225]],[[226]],[[227]],[[228]],[[229]],[[230]],[[231]],[[232]],[[233]],[[234]],[[235]],[[236]],[[237]]],
```

Here is my JS:

```
<script>window.onload = setMap();
```

`function setMap(){`

```
d3.csv("/data/fdata.csv").then(function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
d3.json("/data/a.topojson").then(function(data2) {
        //console.log(data2);

    var width = 960,
        height = 460;

    //create new svg container for the map
    var map = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("class", "map")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
        .center([0, 0])
        .rotate([-2, 0, 0])
        //.parallels([43, 62])
        .scale(175)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    var path = d3.geoPath()
        .projection(projection);

    d3.selectAll(".boundary")
    .style("stroke-width", 1 / 1);
    var b = topojson.feature(data2, data2.objects.ne_10m_admin_0_countries);

    var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();

    var attrArray = ["x1","x2","x3" ];

    function joinData(b, data){
        for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
            var csvRegion = data[i]; //the current region
            var csvKey = data[i].Country; //the CSV primary key

            for (var a=0; a<b.features.length; a++){     
                var geojsonProps = b.features[a].properties; //gj props
                var geojsonKey = geojsonProps.ADMIN; //the geojson primary key

                if (geojsonKey == csvKey){

                    attrArray.forEach(function(attr){
                        var val = parseFloat(csvRegion[attr]); 
                        geojsonProps[attr] = val; 
                    });
                };

            };
        };
        return b;
  };
    joinData(b,data);

    var tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div") 
        .attr("class", "tooltip")       
        .style("opacity", 0);

    var currentF = "B2";

    var color = d3.scaleQuantile()
        .domain(d3.range(0, 1000))
        .range(d3.schemeReds[7]);  

    map.append("path")
        .datum(graticule)
        .attr("class", "graticule")
        .attr("d", path);

    map.append("path")
        .datum(graticule.outline)
        .attr("class", "graticule outline")
        .attr("d", path);

   map.selectAll("path")
        .data(b.features)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", path)
        //.style("stroke", "black")
        .on("mouseover", function(d) {    
            tooltip.transition()    
            .duration(200)    
            .style("opacity", .9)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 1.0);    
            tooltip.html(d.properties.ADMIN)  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")   
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");  
          })          
          .on("mouseout", function(d) {   
            tooltip.transition()    
            .duration(500)    
            .style("opacity", 0)
            .style("stroke-opacity", 0); 
          })
        .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.properties[currentF]); });




}); //csv
}); //json
```

`};`

I believe the issue is with the `map.selectAll("path")` chunk. When I run it without D3 iterating through features it seems to come out fine. (With Indonesia and Malaysia still there. )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
map.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

map.append("path")
    .datum(graticule.outline)
    .attr("class", "graticule outline")
    .attr("d", path);

map.selectAll("path")
    .data(b.features)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", path)
```

The two append statements create paths, you then select these existing paths when you do: `map.selectAll("path")`. To confirm, before you append the features, you can do `console.log(map.selectAll("path").size())` to see how many elements are selected, it should be two.

An enter selection can be used to create elements in the DOM for each item in the data array that does not have a corresponding element in the DOM.

As there are two paths in your selection, the first two items in the data array correspond to these two elements, and thus do not need to be entered: they already exist (*By binding the data with `.data()` you are binding the first two datums in the data array to the already existing paths*). D3 doesn't "know" that these paths aren't supposed to be affiliated with those data array items.

In order to ensure all items are entered you can make sure that you have an empty selection before you bind data:

```
map.selectAll(null).data()...
map.selectAll().data()...
map.selectAll(".className").data()... // where no element has that class yet
```

Comment: Exactly as you said. Console log reported two elements. Went with map.selectAll().data()... and Indonesia and Malaysia are there!!!